# ConstraintLayout layout_constraintHorizontal_bias seems not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="please input test content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Follow pic is preview view.

[image]

I want to move TextView to center_horizontal to parent view , but `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=0.5"` seems not work.

Who has ideas for this problem ? Thanks for first !

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @Nilu  Move TextView to Center Horizontal

Comment: @Cyrus Do you want to achieve this by only ConstraintLayout?

Comment: add android:layout_gravity="center" into textview

Comment: @VishvaDave  Yes, I am learning how to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Cyrus check my below ans and please tell me where to place Edittext

Comment: @VygintasB It seems not work

Comment: @Cyrus Check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="please input test content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT**

to use **`bias`** you need to give constrained it to any parent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer , This way could wrok . but why  'app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=0.5' not work.

Comment: @Cyrus i think no need of `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` check updated ans

Comment: @Cyrus you need toot working because you haven't constrained it to any parent to textview

Comment: Note: The default horizontal bias is 0.5 so you can omit app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"

Answer (score 5):

**Try this:**

> `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` is not working because
>   you haven't constrained it to any parent. [Read more about bias.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="please input test content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Cyrus `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" ` is not working because you haven't constrained it to any parent. try my answer hope it helps.

Comment: same response as @Nilesh

Comment: There is only one answer for solution.. But it's everyone's own way to write it

Comment: @Badyous as you can see nilesh's answer is also same as jesper's answer... Because there is only one answer for this solution... Please remove downvote

Answer (score 3):

First of if i were you i would look at some guides explaining constraint layouts, since you seem to be missing some key elements. [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

When that is said, your problem is that you are asking your layout to constrain at a 0.5 bias to nothing. Your textView is not constrained to anything other than `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"`
Which btw is a little wierd constraining the bottom of your textview to the top of your parent.

In order for bias to work, it needs to know which elements to be biased between. If you simple want it to be center of the parent then constrain the textview to the parent like so:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
```

Also at that point you wont need the bias, i left it in though since you could then use it to move it at other percentages.

Comment: Which i also added in the last line.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need of bias as bias used for spacing between elements since its not require one can constaint to parent from left right bottom and top

Thanks