# Cannot set constraint bias

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I want to set `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"` so that my TextView stays towards left. When I set it from layout editor by dragging the tiny circle to 0, the circle moves back to default 50. Also tried doing it from xml, but the layout has no effect on bias attribute at all. 
If I remove the right constraint, the text goes offscreen owing to wrap_content width. Adding right constraint (along with existing left constraint) requires me to set horizontal bias to achieve permanent left alignment

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902163/6699069) suggests to add constraint to "parent" (instead of another view, I guess), I tried it and set left and right constraints to parent but still no luck. (left was constraint to image view)

I tried left aligning it with another view (by selecting notification_subject and notification_body and using "Align Left Edges"), still no change in layout

This is my TextView

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_subject_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/notification_subject"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TitleTextAppearance"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/notification_item_iv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
```

Rendered layout in editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues here:

1. You are trying to match the constraint by using `layout_width="0dp"`. I believe this should be set to `layout_width="wrap_content"`.
2. On one side of your constraints you are using `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` and then `layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/notification_item_iv"` on the opposite side. Please can you change this to `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/notification_item_iv"`

Complete code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_subject_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/notification_subject"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TitleTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/notification_item_iv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
```

Comment: 0dp in xml implies 'match_constraint' in layout editor.